# Why does my ikfast solver work outisde of MoveIt! but not within?

Tags: ros, moveit, ik, ikfast, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm steadily making progress with my project to control a 3DOF arm but there is this problem that been annoying me for the last couple of days.

I'm trying to make a ikfast plugin for MoveIt! following the official tutorial. Everything seems to be working well, I test the solver using the compute program as instructed [here (section 6)](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution) and everything seems to be working fine. I first test by using the fk solver, I then use the position returned by the fk solver to test the ik solver. As you can see, it seems to work well.

[image: image description]

When I proceed to build the moveit plugin however and attempt to move the robot arm in a python script, the planning fails - as shown below. I've tried everything, I've tried setting the tolerances higher, I've tried using the same pose returned by get current pose. Nothing seems to work.

[image: image description]

Here is the code I'm using:

[image: image description]

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I'm kind of stuck at the moment.

Billy

ifast plugin tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution
python commander tutorial: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205357/why-does-my-ikfast-solver-work-outisde-of-moveit!-but-not-within?/) by [auldwin1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21870/auldwin1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to update this. The solutions was to fix my model.

---

Originally posted by [auldwin1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21870/auldwin1/) with karma: 81 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0